# Updating a Foreign Key constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE not updating?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We've realised in our SQL Server 2005 DB that some Foreign Keys don't have the On Delete Cascade property set, which is giving us a couple of referential errors when we try and delete some records.

Use the Management Studio I scripted the `DROP` and `CREATE`SQL's, but it seems that the `CREATE` isn't working correctly.

The `DROP`:

```
USE [FootprintReports]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK__SUBSCRIPTIONS_Reports]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[_SUBSCRIPTIONS]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_SUBSCRIPTIONS] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__SUBSCRIPTIONS_Reports]
```

and the `CREATE`

```
USE [FootprintReports]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_SUBSCRIPTIONS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__SUBSCRIPTIONS_Reports] FOREIGN KEY([PARAMETER_ReportID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reports] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_SUBSCRIPTIONS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__SUBSCRIPTIONS_Reports]
```

If I manually change the value of the On Delete in the GUI, after dropping and recreating, the On Delete isn't correctly updated.

As a test, I set the Delete rule in the GUI to `Set Null`.
It dropped correctly, and recreated without error.
If I got back into the GUI, it is still showing the `Set Null` as the Delete Rule.

Have I done something wrong? or is there another way to edit a constraint to add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach looks correct. `ALTER TABLE` is the only way to edit a constraint. Perhaps Management Studio is needs a data refresh.  Try right-click Refresh, or close the app and reopen it.

Comment: Yep, this was the issue. For some reason the Management Studio was still showing the old value. I had to close the app and restart it before it would display the change. Thanks!